# Unable to push to remote files in github

Tags: github, github-pages

when I enter the "push origin master" command this error shows up, what to do?

error message -  "fatal: unable to access 'https://git.com/LokeshKarki/Java-Core-Advance-Program.git/': SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'git.com'"

and yes I tried this command to -  "git config --global http.sslVerify false"
then entering the "push origin master" command 
and then this error message show up - "fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://git.com/LokeshKarki/Java-Core-Advance-Program.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://venture.com/domains/git.com"

I want to push my local files to my private repo on github.

Comment: The name of the site is `github.com`, not `git.com`.

Comment: Do not use the github tag for git related issues.

Comment: I have used github only. Point me at where  you want me to change.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your remote url is set incorrectly with `git.com` instead of `github.com`. Correct the same with the below command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/LokeshKarki/Java-Core-Advance-Program.git
```

Then try pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

The domain you are using is wrong.

You are using:  https://git.com/.....

What you should use:  https://github.com/.....

So in short, I think you are using the wrong url